# How can I select rows without specific duplicate columns

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
id    name    type    creator    reason    guild
1     hi      in                           322
2     hi      out     some                 322
3     hi      in                           322
4     ok      in                           322
```

I want all columns and rows where the name, type and guild are not the same

```
select distinct name, type, guild
```

But I want to keep the other columns in the above result as well, I am using a sqlite database

Output of the above:

```
hi  in  322
hi  out 322
ok  in  322
```

The output is missing the other columns

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: If you only want one row per `name, type, guild` which values should the other columns have? i.e. which row are they pulled from?

Comment: You may want to specify the database you're working with. SQL is just a language, and its dialects differ between DBMSes.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Poor sample data, have different guild values for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments it seems you need row_number() with order by id

```
   select name, type, guild,creator,reason
    from (select name, type, guild,creator,reason, 
        row_number() 
        over (partition by name, type, guild order by guild) as rn
          from players 
         ) t
    where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I was still facing problems using your and the other example, I hope this is more clear

Comment: @Rezy for the above sample data what will be your output

Comment: It creates random 3 exact duplicate rows multiple times

Comment: @Rezy i said what will the output from the among sample show us in question

Comment: Added expected output @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: But now the creator and reason are missing in the output @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @Rezy added those in output

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` is often used for this purpose:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by name, type, guild order by name) as seqnum
      from players p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```